# Classifying a branch as master or dev

Tags: javascript

I am dealing constantly with the following code.

The thing is that literally it makes no sense for me to have all the spacing and divisions in the if-else when the code is so small that can be a block by itself.

When I read a line within line breaks I expect something difficult to understand or something that should be paid special care to be read about. Not just a line break after each function or if definition by default.

```
if (branchInfo.name === BRANCHNAMES.MASTER) {

    branchInfo.isMaster = true;

} else if (
    branchInfo.name === BRANCHNAMES.RELEASE ||
    branchInfo.name === BRANCHNAMES.HOTFIX
) {

    branchInfo.isDev = true;

}
```

Given that the line doesn't exceed the 120 characters and that they are small `truthy` statements that don't deserve to get a function, I want to remove that unnecessary split in the `else if` because it doesn't seem necessary, almost like the other line breaks and in my opinion it just leads into weird code.

```
if (branchInfo.name === BRANCHNAMES.MASTER) {
    branchInfo.isMaster = true;
} else if (branchInfo.name === BRANCHNAMES.RELEASE || branchInfo.name === BRANCHNAMES.HOTFIX) {
    branchInfo.isDev = true;
}
```

Am I being over paranoid about it? Is this actually a good practice?

PS: I know a good practice is to keep into a coding style and always keep it as it is, but really, I can't stand some things that just make code look weird. Sometimes too many line breaks also lead into unreadable code, don't you think so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I see no problem doing it either way. I prefer to keep my lines shorter than that but 120ish characters isn't unreasonable.

Another option you have is to store those values in some other variables and use those instead.

```
let isMaster = branchInfo.name === BRANCHNAMES.MASTER;
let isRelease = branchInfo.name === BRANCHNAMES.RELEASE;
let isHotfix = branchInfo.name === BRANCHNAMES.HOTFIX;
if (isMaster) {
    branchInfo.isMaster = true;
} else if (isRelease || isHotfix) {
    branchInfo.isDev = true;
}
```

Another way would be to use a `switch` statement with `case` fallthrough. Some people refuse to allow fallthrough so it's your call.

```
switch (branchInfo.name) {
    case BRANCHNAMES.MASTER:
        branchInfo.isMaster = true;
        break;

    case BRANCHNAMES.RELEASE:
    case BRANCHNAMES.HOTFIX:
        branchInfo.isDev = true;
}
```

Finally, I would consider just assigning directly.

```
branchInfo.isMaster = branchInfo.name === BRANCHNAMES.MASTER;
branchInfo.isDev = branchInfo.name === BRANCHNAMES.RELEASE ||
                   branchInfo.name === BRANCHNAMES.HOTFIX;
```

There's also one trick I use if I need to compare against multiple things at once.

```
let devBranches = [BRANCHNAMES.RELEASE, BRANCHNAMES.HOTFIX];
branchInfo.isMaster = branchInfo.name === BRANCHNAMES.MASTER;
branchInfo.isDev = devBranches.includes(branchInfo.name);
```

If you don't perform any extra work in either branch of the `if` statement, I would use the last or second to last option. If you need to perform additional work, I would use the additional variables to make it more readable.

Comment: Thanks, it's always nice to see how other people approach code cleanup, all of them are nice ideas!